# Поиск в JSON / словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер

Есть данные приходящие от сервера. Довольно большой объем данных. Интересно можно как-то удобно распарсить json? Умею делать это через словари, но там нужно проходитья по всему словарю. Это удобно, но ответ от сервера приходит с большим кол-вом вложенных элементов, и цикл превращается в пирамиду. Есть какие-то решения или библиотеки?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: на вскидку - модуль [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/) позволяет искать в словарях, используя технику, схожую с `xpath`

Comment: На вскидку: либо рекурсия - если в данных подразумевается фрактальная вложенность, либо отдельная функция для каждого отдельного типа элемента, причём функции могут вызывать друг друга.